# What consequences would have to be behind in versions regarding

Tags: angular

This is kind of a meta question (about the language/platform) so I'm sorry in advance if this is useless. The reason I still ask is because I've seen a lot of people confused about RC3, RC in general, and I might be the most confused out there (so it might give some perspective to new people coming to learn new things like me).

This past week I've been doing as much research as I could, to try and understand Routes, to try and learn how could I update from beta.8 version to RC3, so as to not lag behind, and many other things. I am very new to all of this, to , not just angular, but I find it very satisfying to be developing something so new.

I just got told to not try to update, and first finish all other tasks (mainly, connect front and back end as to show something working from beginning to end).

I found out I'm not properly able to explain what does it mean to be behind in versions. I do not know when is this going to start being a problem rather than a nuisance, or when will components stop working.

So I wanted to know, what is the right mindset for this type of development(when new updates are being released so frequently, certain things stop working how you learned them a few months ago...)?

**Is it bad, and if so, how bad, to stay with an old version simply because it works?**

All of it talking in this specific context of having an old version working, but that it was done a mere couple months back.

Comment: More context info is needed to provide helpful answers. One of my first questions is: Are you talking about a commercial app that is already released or supposed to be released soon? Second: Which parts of Angular 2 are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talking about Angular 2 I think you have to make the effort to upgrade to version 2.0 once it's released.

Meanwhile I noticed many developers complaining their external components not working with latest RC.x for example `angular2-modal` not working with RC4, but works fine with RC1.

So when version 2.0 is released you'll notice all third party developers upgrading their libraries. My advice is to wait a week or two after that and only then consider upgrading.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Half the motivation to ask was because I was looking at how would I use some developers software (ng2-material, for example, seems to have updated to rc1 but they also seem to be developing something new, that kind of stuff). So it's great to have that in mind

Answer (score 1):

Each strategy (update early, update late) has advantages and disadvantages. This is just about what disadvantages you are more comfortable with and with advantages are how important to you.

If you stick with an old version you might invest a lot of time to work around bugs or missing features that are already fixed in newer versions.
The advantage is that it is well known what is working well and what needs to be worked around and how. Dependencies compatible with the older versions are usually available probably with the same advantages and drawbacks and the older Angular2 version itself.

If you update early you might invest a lot of time to figure out how to use new features and you might run into new bugs that are not yet fixed.
The advantage is that you invest your time in the future and not in something that is already deprecated. Dependencies compatible with your current Angular2 version might not yet be available.

Usually its a good strategy to find some way in the middle, but hard to tell what that actually is.

Currently the biggest hurdle is the router. The changes were substantial. If you are busy learning how the old router works, the time is better invested if you use it to learn the new router. If the older version provides all the features you need to implement your application and you are already experienced with it, it might be worth continue working with the older version until the newer version becomes more stable.

Comment: I think this is a nice way of looking at it, looking for balance. Interesting. I am kind of in the middle of old and new routing, since I've tried to understand how the new router works but now I have to use the old one (since I won't upgrade for a while). I would also like to ask, since a lot of things have been deprecated, what is the chance of my code simply not working anymore, because it becomes not supported or something like that. Is it a possibility to keep in mind, is it too far in the future, or is something unlikely to happen?

Comment: If you stick with the versions of tools and dependencies that you are currently using I assume you'll have a few years. If you for example update angular-cli, material2 components, ...,  you will be out of luck pretty soon I guess.

Comment: What do you mean "update material2, angular cli"? Because if you didn't mean to NOT update, I don't really get it, mind expanding a tiny bit there? Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Yes, I mean "don't update anything" and you are safe